# need to add default value in f.select field to existing ones - rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

With the code I have below in the select field I have all the `public_campaigns`:

```
<%= f.select :campaign_id, @public_campaigns.map{|x| [x.name,x.id]} %>
```

`public_campaigns` is defined in controller with:

```
@public_campaigns = @logged_in_user.campaigns.order('created_at desc')
```

In the form I select the `campaign` and fill up the rest of the form and at the submit action an invitation is created with `campaign_id` taken from the `campaign` I selected in the form, it can be anything from `1` to `n`

What I need now is to have a `default item` in select field that will have the value of `0` and named `"No campaign"`, it means I invite someone to a campaign that I have not created yet and in invitation the `campaign_id` field will be `0`.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need 0? I think use of {:include_blank => "No campaign"} should be enough?

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :campaign_id, (@public_campaigns.map{|x| [x.name,x.id]} << ["No campaign",0]), {:selected => 0} %>
```

Comment: thanks, this is the answer at my question that's why I accept your answer, short and right on target.. meantime we have changed the way the select will behave and prusswan is the one who helped me here. Thank you ;) 1 vote

Answer (score 1):

Well, the fastest way you can do this is something like this:

```
@public_campaigns = @logged_in_user.campaigns.order('created_at desc')
no_campaign = Campaign.new(:id => '0', :name => 'No Campaign')
@public_campaigns.unshift(no_campaign)
```

Comment: ok, did it your way, but the "No campaign" element has no value for it, how can I assign it to be 0. I checked in inspect element and it has no value <option value="">No Campaign</option>

Comment: Try using a string value for id, maybe that fix it. `:id => '0'`. Also, you don't really need a value for a default option as it would never be selected.

Comment: still the value of No campaign is empty. thank you, I solved it with the answer of sufleR.. as I asked to have an element with value 0, with his method I have it 0. 1 vote from me anyway. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are unable to do it this way:

```
<%= f.collection_select :campaign_id, @public_campaigns, :id, :name, prompt: 'No campaign' %>
```

Just check if `campaign_id.nil?` instead of assigning any value to `campaign_id`

Comment: "Just check if campaign_id.nil? instead of assigning any value to campaign_id" - that's exactly how we changed it to behave, thank you.